# Múltiplos pipelines para tratar spiders diferentes no Scrapy

Tags: python, aplicação-web, web-crawler, scrapy

Como tratar o pipelines.py quando temos diferentes spiders?

Exemplo: Tenho uma Spider que trabalha obtendo posts de um determinado blog e outra salvando imagens de banners em jpeg encontrados em cada página. As duas spiders funcionam, mas utilizo o mesmo pipeline para persistir os objetos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É um padrão comum nos pipelines (e em spider middlewares também) usar atributos do spider para decidir o que fazer:

```
class MyPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if getattr(spider, 'my_pipeline_enabled', False):
            # faz a coisa aqui
```

Dessa forma, apesar do pipeline estar habilitado no projeto inteiro, você pode usar o atributo `my_pipeline_enabled` para habilitar o pipeline apenas para os spiders que quiser.

Você também pode expandir esse código pra considerar uma configuração, se necessário.

No Scrapy 0.25+ (ainda não lançado, por enquanto só pegando do repo Git), tem também a alternativa de usar configurações no spider que têm precedência sobre as do projeto.